# Provoking a coditional inside a binary

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, binaryfiles

i'm doing some reverse engineering with ghidra, I have a binary file, which prompts me for a password, and if I type correctly, I get a flag.

The generated c-code for exactly this looks like this:

```
  __isoc99_scanf(&DAT_00400a82,local_28);
  __s2 = (char *)FUN_0040078d(0x14);
  iVar1 = strcmp(local_28,__s2);
  if (iVar1 == 0) {
    FUN_00400978(&local_48);
  }
```

So it takes a value from the user, and compares it to the output of function call `FUN_0040078d(0x14)`. Now, I have been looking at this quite a bit, and `FUN_0040078d` is non-deterministic, uses quite a bit of randomness, so I know that i can't predict what it's output is going to be. But it's a chararray of length 14.
In case you're wondering, it looks like this:

```
void * FUN_0040078d(int param_1)

{
  int iVar1;
  time_t tVar2;
  void *pvVar3;
  int local_c;
  
  tVar2 = time((time_t *)0x0);
  DAT_00601074 = DAT_00601074 + 1;
  srand(DAT_00601074 + (int)tVar2 * param_1);
  pvVar3 = malloc((long)(param_1 + 1));
  if (pvVar3 != (void *)0x0) {
    local_c = 0;
    while (local_c < param_1) {
      iVar1 = rand();
      *(char *)((long)local_c + (long)pvVar3) = (char)(iVar1 % 0x5e) + '!';
      local_c = local_c + 1;
    }
    *(undefined *)((long)pvVar3 + (long)param_1) = 0;
    return pvVar3;
  }
                    /* WARNING: Subroutine does not return */
  exit(1);
}
```

So now what I want to do, is I want to be able to enter the conditional form the first code snippet that I showed here, without being able to predict __s2`.

Is there any tools or techniques that can assist me in doing this?

Comment: Disassemble, find the conditional branch instruction that would jump over the call to `FUN_00400978(&local_48);` when the test fails, overwrite the conditional branch with `nop`s so that the jump isn't taken?

Comment: Or, if you don't get to patch the binary, still you can probably replicate the string generated by `FUN_0040078d` if you just run the same algorithm yourself, using the same system `rand` function and seeding with the current time.  If you can get it your input in time so that it runs its seed before the next second ticks over, you should get the same result.

Comment: yes, I i'm still a bit lost :D how would I for example jump over wiht `nop`, and what does that even mean?